# Android - get currently playing song duration and elapsed time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I'm trying to get the duration of the song that currently playing in the music player.
I'm using the code below, and able to get the artist name, track name and a few other details, but can't find the duration and elapsed time. Is there any other way to find it?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");

    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");

    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");     
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");        
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");

    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    //HTC Music
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
    //MIUI Player
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
    //Real
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    //SEMC Music Player
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcontrol.ACTION_TRACK_STARTED");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcontrol.ACTION_PAUSED");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.TRACK_COMPLETED");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playstatechanged");
    //rdio
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.playstatechanged");
    //Samsung Music Player
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
    //Winamp
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.playstatechanged");
    //Amazon
    iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.playstatechanged");
    //Rhapsody
    iF.addAction("com.rhapsody.playstatechanged");
    //PowerAmp
    iF.addAction("com.maxmpz.audioplayer.playstatechanged");
    //will be added any....
    //scrobblers detect for players (poweramp for example)
    //Last.fm
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.playbackpaused");
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.playbackcomplete");
    //A simple last.fm scrobbler
    iF.addAction("com.adam.aslfms.notify.playstatechanged");
    //Scrobble Droid
    iF.addAction("net.jjc1138.android.scrobbler.action.MUSIC_STATUS");

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
        Log.v("yossi", extra.toString());

    }
};
```

Comment: Where did you put that code?

Answer (score 1):

You will get duration of song by using following intents.But is supports only for few players.Please try it

```
duration    =intent.getLongExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION, 0);
duration    =intent.getLongExtra("duration", 0);
```

Comment: which player you used .?

Comment: The default player of android. In which player it suppose to work?

Comment: @Yossi :It will work on Deezer Music,Google play music